# Get OPERATOR From Argument Of Macro Function Using C

Tags: c, function, macros

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

How Can Get OPERATOR From Argument Of Macro Function Using C?

### Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define dooo(oooo) (age) oooo=5;

int age=38;
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    dooo(+);
    dooo(*);
    printf("===>%d\n",age);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: macros are text replacements, e.g. for `dooo(+)` just insert the macro definition "(age) ..."  in the code replacing oooo by + and see what you get. But **don't ever** write code like that!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operators like `+=` are a single token. So to generate them in a macro from partial tokens, you need to use the token concatenation operator `##`:

```
#define dooo(oooo) (age) oooo##= 5;
```

This will combine what `oooo` expands to (`+` or `*`) with `=` into a single token.

Comment: Wooow , thank you. :like: